# Laravel transactions don't rollback on exception in MySQL with InnoDB engine

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this transaction, and all my MySQL tables are using InnoDB engine:

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
try{
    User::create([
        'name' => 'test',
        'status' => 1
    ]);
    array_push($test_array, ['test']);
    \DB::commit();

} catch(\Exception $e){
    \DB::rollBack();
}
```

If I `dump()` the exception, it says:

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

because `$test_array` is null. However, the transaction doesn't rollback, and the `user` is still created. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I get the same result while doing this too :

```
\DB::transaction(function () {

    User::create([
        'name' => 'test',
        'status' => 1
    ]);
    array_push($test_array, ['test']);
});
```

Comment: Any help https://fideloper.com/laravel-database-transactions

Comment: Are you using multiple database connections?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir No, only one.

Comment: Does `\DB::beginTransaction(); User::create([...]); \DB::rollBack();` have the same issue? Please double-check that the table is actually using the `InnoDB` engine.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I doubled checked, same problem. Do transactions rollback only on QueryException ? or any Exception ?

Comment: An exception itself doesn't rollback the transaction. A rollback happens when you call `DB::rollBack()` or when the database connection ends without you calling `DB::commit();`.

Comment: Please log the executed queries: `\DB::enableQueryLog(); \DB::beginTransaction(); User::create([...]); \DB::rollBack(); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`